# Please help me to prove why this calculous equation is right.$\int_0^z\frac{{(\lambda x)}^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}dx=\frac{{(\lambda z)}^k}{\lambda k!}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

$$\int_0^z\frac{{(\lambda x)}^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}dx=\frac{{(\lambda z)}^k}{\lambda k!}$$
I have tried long time to prove this equation is right but still do not get it.
I think employing some formula can prove it, but do not have any idea.
Please help me. Thank you!!

Comment: Hint: take the $\lambda^{k-1}$ and $(k-1)!$ out of the integral, since they are just constants.

Comment: Write the integrand as $\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\cdot x^{k-1}$ and move the constant factor outside the integral. What is $\int_0^z x^{k-1}\,dx$?

Comment: Thank you all, I think I have thought it in too complicated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The only nonconstant term in the integrand is $x^{k-1}$.